# Problem in downloading specific bands of one Sentinel product

Tags: python, sentinel-hub, sentinel

I'm working on developing software through it user can upload a `.shp` file containing some areas and see the `NDVI` as a `WMS` layer on map. To achieve this, at first step, after uploading spatial data by user, the software starts downloading two `Red` and `NIR` bands and then calculates the `NDVI`.

Sentinel gives a good solution for this purpose by introducing `make_path_filter` [method](https://sentinelsat.readthedocs.io/en/master/api_reference.html#sentinelsat.products.make_path_filter) that generates function to limit the content to be downloaded to only those we need instead of downloading the whold `.zip` file which is much larger in size.

Here is my code:

```py
import os
import ogr
from typing import *
from datetime import date
from sentinelsat import SentinelAPI, make_path_filter

sentinel_api = SentinelAPI(<username>, <password>)

def shape_to_wkt(path: str) -> str:
    '''
    This returns WKT string from shapefile.
    \nArguments:
    path: /path/to/the/shape/file/name.shp
    \nReturns:
    WKT string
    '''

def get_product_id(extent: str, platform: str, start_date: str, end_date: str, max_cloud: int) -> List:
    '''
    This fetches product id of Sentinel-1 or -2 imagery data
    from Sentinel Data Hub through certieria
    \nArguments:
    extent: WKT format for spatial extent [Polygon]
    platform: mission name (e.g. Sentinel-1, Sentinel-2)
    start_date: Staring from
    end_date: End to
    max_cloud: max percentage of cloud coverage [0~100]
    \nReturns:
    A list of <product_id> to be downloaded
    '''

shapefile_path = '/path/to/<name>.shp'
interesting_area = shape_to_wkt(shapefile_path)

product_ids = get_product_id(
    interesting_area,
    "Sentinel-2",
    date(2021, 5, 1),
    date(2021, 7, 10),
    0)

for id in product_ids:
    try:
        nodefilter = make_path_filter("*_B0[48].jp2")
        sentinel_api.download(id, f'./imagery/{id}', nodefilter=nodefilter)
        print('\nDownloading')
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'\nError in downloading <<{id}>> : {e}')
```

I am applying `"*_B0[48].jp2"` pattern to download only required bands in which `B0[48]` referes to `Band 04` means `Red` and `Band 08` means`NIR` respectively. The code works fine but the **problem** is `make_path_filter` **doesn't work** and the downloader is still downloading the whole `.zip` file and I couldn't figure it out where my mistake is.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with the original function as stated here https://github.com/sentinelsat/sentinelsat/issues/540#issuecomment-920883495 by Antonio Valentino.
I was able to successfully download specific bands.

```
from sentinelsat import SentinelAPI, make_path_filter
path_filter = make_path_filter("*_B0[2348]_10m.jp2")
```

Also using your matching format it will download only the manifest.safefile.